# Rerendering issue in React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to re render my browser every time cart is updated to update the `calculatedPrice` state of a cart. I can do this in `useEffect` with having `cart` in the box but I'm also fetching data in `useEffect` so each time the cart is updated my browser is refetching from an API. Is there a way I can do this without re fetching from the API?

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const result = await axios(API)
            const items = result.data.data.items.map((item) => {
                item.count = 0
                return item
            })
            setProducts(items)
        }
        fetchData()
        setCalculatePrice(() =>
            cart.reduce((price, product) => price + product.price, 0).toFixed(2),
        )
    }, [cart])
```

updateCart function

```
const updateCart = React.useCallback(
        (product, index) => {
            const newCart = removeItemOnce(cart, product)
            products[index].count = products[index].count - 1
            setCart([...newCart])
            setProducts(products)
        },
        [cart, products],
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have separated useEffects. It's even advisable to have them separated. So in your case I would do:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const result = await axios(API)
        const items = result.data.data.items.map((item) => {
            item.count = 0
            return item
        })
        setProducts(items)
    }
    fetchData();
}, [])
```

This will be called on component mount once.
And for cart update

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setCalculatePrice(() =>
        cart.reduce((price, product) => price + product.price, 0).toFixed(2),
    );
}, [cart]);
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: OMG I didn't even know you can use it twice and this works perfectly! thank you sooo much